# pkexec - how do I set a custom timeout for auth_admin_keep when writting a pkexec policy

Tags: polkit, pkexec

I was just reading the reference manual written by David Z for pkexec on freedesktop.org:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html

and

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/pkexec.1.html

Manual says that using the auth_admin_keep option will only keep your password for 5 to 15 minutes and that if we want to set custom timeouts we have write custom rules.

Would anyone know how I can go about writing a custom rules for the timeout? I tried to follow along with the manual but I'm not a coder and I wasn't being able to understand the synthax, no were there any mentions made of timeout related synthax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately the timeout appears to be hard-coded as 5 minutes in the PolicyKit upstream source, [in file `src/polkitbackend/polkitbackendinteractiveauthority.c`.](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/polkit/tree/src/polkitbackend/polkitbackendinteractiveauthority.c)

On lines 3231-3236 it says:

```
/* TODO: right now the time the temporary authorization is kept is hard-coded - we
 *       could make it a propery on the PolkitBackendInteractiveAuthority class (so
 *       the local authority could read it from a config file) or a vfunc
 *       (so the local authority could read it from an annotation on the action).
 */
 expiration_seconds = 5 * 60;
```

So, the timeout is set to 5 minutes within the source code, and there are currently no provisions for changing it without recompiling the appropriate parts of PolicyKit.

On the other hand, [OpenSuSE Leap 15 seems to have extended this functionality.](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/security/html/book.security/cha.security.policykit.html) They seem to have re-interpreted the `..._keep` actions to mean "remember authentication while the asking process is running", and added `..._keep_session` and `..._keep_always` actions to mean "remember for the entirety of this specific login session" and "remember forever", respectively.

Comment: Please, someone do this! Many users from all distributions would greatly benefit from it!

Comment: Gentoo users may put this patch into `/etc/portage/patches/sys-auth/polkit/30-minutes.patch` to change the delay: https://gist.github.com/PF4Public/cf223fa1f9614b92dba2b64474226fff